# How to allow a Tab Bar Item to have multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now and any help would be appreciated.

I have a `UITabBarController` that has four `TabBarItem`s.

I want to determine what view controller is displayed to the user depending on whether the user is logged in.

For example when the user is not logged in, I want to display different login screen depending on which `TabBarItem` is selected - each login will look different. When the user is logged in I want to display normal content the selected `TabBarItem`

I was thinking of having multiple `ViewController`s for each tab bar item. When a user selects a `TabBarItem`, determine if the user is logged in and then display the correct ```ViewController. I'm not sure if this is the right approach and how to achieve this behaviour.

**Update**:
This is the solution I have come up with but was wondering what everyone thinks - whether it's the right approach.
This is what my Storyboard looks like:
[image]

The idea is when the user is logged in I would show the login view controllers and when the user is not logged in I would show the logged out view controllers.

I would be using the `self.present(...)` to change to and from the login and logout `ViewController`s.

Comment: can you pls add your current code

Answer (score 1):

You can change your displayed tabs with [`setViewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621177-setviewcontrollers). Simply set the array of desired viewControllers when user logs in or logs out.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    func onMyLogin() {
        setViewControllers(myNormalViewControllers, animated: false)
    }
    func onMyLogout() {
        setViewControllers(myUnidentifiedViewControllers, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it out today. I've also updated my question with a possible solution I've thought of. Curious to see what your thoughts are

Comment: @breaktop your solution works too. It's a matter of taste on how you want to animate the transition between the two states; and in current case I prefer my solution of a single TabBarController with a native `animated: true`.

Comment: CAn you give the answer in objective c